# How to observe within Viewmodel in Android Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-viewmodel

Below is my viewmodel class body

```
    private var _movieState = mutableStateOf(false)
    val movieState = _movieState
    
   private val query = if (_movieState.value) ListState.POPULAR_PLAYING else ListState.ALL_PLAYING

    
    
    val moviesData: Flow<PagingData<Movie>> = Pager(PagingConfig(pageSize = 10)) {
        MoviePagingSource(movieRepository, query.string)
    }.flow
```

And I have Two function which populate the Boolean value

```
  fun setListToPopular(){
    _movieState.value = true
}
fun setListToAllNowPlaying(){
    _movieState.value = false
}
```

which will be triger from UI

Now i have one mistake once the code of viewmodel runs my if block is over but i want to observe that Boolean state within it.

how should i do that ?

Comment: I want show movieData according to user click it has two option , by which we request to our query.

Comment: I think you want to make a `Flow` out of your `query` property and then use `combine()` as described [here](https://kt.academy/article/cc-flow-combine) to create a third `Flow` (let's call it `finalMoviesData`). That way, changes to either `query` or `movieData` will trigger a new result in `finalMoviesData`.

Comment: @GavinWright I'm little confuse in this, please fix and tell me how to do.
Github Link of viewmodel https://github.com/ashgautamDev/NowPlaying-App/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/ashish/nowplayingapp/viewmodel/MainViewModel.kt